Get current test method in JUnit 5 using a static mehtod
Is there a way to identify currently running test method (or that the code is not running as part of a test method) in JUnit 5 using a static method (i.e. no matter from where it's called)?.
I'm not looking for stuff like injecting TestInfo or ExtensionContext.getTestMethod(). I'd like something that doesn't required any changes in the test class code, like a static method.

Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() then analyse the stack trace?

Try running your all test case as coverage option. Eclipse -> Run as Coverage-> Junit test. This will highlight code and test case which run successfully as Green color and those who failed or did not get covered will be shown as red color.
